# Fickle execution time of Google cloud function which reads from Firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I wrote the simplest Google cloud function which reads several documents from a Firestore collection.

```
async function loadCodes()
{
  
  var errorCodes = [];
    let errorsRef = firestore.collection(ERROR_CODES_COLLECTION_NAME)
    .where("EntityNumber", "==", 7);
    try {
      await errorsRef.get()
      .then(qs => {
        qs.forEach(doc => {
          errorCodes.push(doc.data());
        });
      });

      
      return errorCodes;
    }
    catch (err) {
```

....
I invoked the function many times for several minutes.
In most cases, the execution time was about 60 ms as expected. But in 10-15% of cases, it takes 1.5 - 2 seconds.

How may it be explained and if is it possible to avoid?

Comment: Cloud Functions doesn't give predictable function execution times, especially due to the unpredictable cost of cold starts, and possibly other things.  But without the complete code, reproduction steps, and exact data you're working with, it's hard to tell for sure.

Comment: OK Doug, Cold start is not an issue here because I invoke the function several times for short period of time. The question is what are other things that cause the ×20 growth of execution time?

Comment: Additionally. If I get a single document from the collection, the function works stable and it's execution time is always about 50 me.

Comment: Where do you run the code? Are you sure you have stable connection? I think you would try to run it in Active Cloud Shell in GCP.....

Comment: This is a cloud function with http trigger. I run it using Google cloud console.

Comment: "But without the complete code, reproduction steps, and exact data you're working with, it's hard to tell for sure."

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the matter is that loadCodes() is a global function.
Getting documents from the collection really takes nearly one second, but because of this is a global function Google saves it (with its result) in a cache. So, in most cases, the loadCodes() is not actually invoked and whole cloud function executing time is short. When Google decides to refresh the environment, LoadCodes really performs its jobs and it takes time.